# Comparator A && B from select tag, and produce C

Tags: javascript, html, dom

How can I compare both "statement A" and "Statement B" if is selected from dropdown menu, so that I can produce "C" results in somewhere else

Like let says, if A && B is selected, then change DOM " " into C.

code as below

```
  <select id="imgList">
    <option value="images/a.png" data-description="a">a</option>
    <option value="images/b.png" data-description="b">b</option>
    <option value="images/c.png" data-description="c">c</option>
    <option value="images/d.png" data-description="d">d</option>
  </select>

  <select id="imgList2">
    <option value="images/a.png" data-description="a">a</option>
    <option value="images/b.png" data-description="b">b</option>
    <option value="images/c.png" data-description="c">c</option>
    <option value="images/d.png" data-description="d">d</option>
  </select>
```

And

```
if (document.getElementById('imgList').value == 'images/a.png'&&
    document.getElementById('imgList2').value == 'images/b.png') {
    console.log("you got C");}
```

Comment: It's unclear what *"then change DOM"* means. But what you have so far seems fine. What exactly are you having problems with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the onchange event handler like this :

```
 <select id="imgList" onchange="compare()">
    <option value="images/a.png" data-description="a">a</option>
    <option value="images/b.png" data-description="b">b</option>
    <option value="images/c.png" data-description="c">c</option>
    <option value="images/d.png" data-description="d">d</option>
  </select>

  <select id="imgList2" onchange="compare()">
    <option value="images/a.png" data-description="a">a</option>
    <option value="images/b.png" data-description="b">b</option>
    <option value="images/c.png" data-description="c">c</option>
    <option value="images/d.png" data-description="d">d</option>
  </select>

function compare()
{
    if (document.getElementById('imgList').value == 'images/a.png'&& document.getElementById('imgList2').value == 'images/b.png') {
        console.log("you got C");
    }
}
```

Documentation here : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp